# Basic probability of at least one independent event happening

Tags: probability

If four people are in a room for 1 hour, each on their own very old laptop and each laptop has a 10% chance of crashing during that time, then I thought the probability of at least one laptop crashing would be:

1/10 + 1/10 + 1/10 + 1/10 = 2/5

But then if the chance of crashing was 25% it would then be:

1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 = 1

Obviously there is not a 100% chance of of at least one crashing so I have got this completely wrong.

Is this the kind of thing where I should be calculating the chances of no laptop crashing and working out that way?

Thanks

Comment: Good instincts.  As you suspect, it's best to work from the complement.  The probability that none of them crash is $\left(\frac 9{10}\right)^4$ so your answer is $1-\left(\frac 9{10}\right)^4$.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that for 10 laptops and there was a 35% of none of them crashing. I thought that was too high so thought I must be doing it wrong. My brain can't really process it!

Comment: The issue with your argument is that you conflated independent events with mutually exclusive events. Probabilities only add like $P(A\text{ or } B) = P(A)+P(B)$ when it is not possible for both $A$ and $B$ to occur (mutually exclusive). Think flipping heads or tails on a coin.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to get intuition.  I agree with the $35\%$ for ten, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a binomial distribution where $n=4,p=\frac{1}{10}$

$P[n,k]=\binom{n}{k}*p^k*(1-p)^{n-k}$

$P[4,1]=\binom{4}{1}*(0.1)^1*(0.9)^3=0.2916$

$P[4,2]=\binom{4}{2}*(0.1)^2*(0.9)^2=0.0486$

$P[4,3]=\binom{4}{3}*(0.1)^3*(0.9)^1=0.0036$

$P[4,4]=\binom{4}{4}*(0.1)^4*(0.9)^0=0.0001$

Adding all these probabilities, we get the probability that at least one old laptop will crash during the one hour time period.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you dont care anoit the number of worling machines, partition the sample space: $A_1, A_2 \ldots A_n$. The probability of all machinrs crashing, assuming independence is the probability of the intersect of all these events. If you take the compliment to this subset, you get subsets that include at least one other(maybe all) machine working. Hence lulu's result